# ClassNotFoundException Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make my website live but keep getting the same error...I've tried looking everywhere and using everyone solution with no luck.

**Error**

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DestinationAppBundle" from namespace "Destination\AppBundle" in /home/dcms/public/html/dcms/apha/app/AppKernel.php line 19. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

**AppKernel.php**

```
    public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Destination\AppBundle\DestinationAppBundle(),
        new Destination\Auth\HashInterfaceBundle\DestinationHashInterfaceBundle(),
    );
```

File Structure

```
src
    Destination
        AppBundle
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using APC? Try flushing it.

Comment: how would you do that in php?

Comment: make sure you have `DestinationAppBundle.php` in live host. if it's work localy that means your project is not uploaded correctly, use rsync to make sure everything is sync (if you canuse rsync).

Comment: Already tried reuploading whole site twice

Comment: Upload a script with `phpinfo();` to see if APC is installed. If it is you can try calling `apc_clear_cache()` to flush it.

Comment: After calling apc_clear_cache, nothing was happing, i have always this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**first:** check if the file `src\Destination\AppBundle\DestinationAppBundle.php` does exist

**second:** open `DestinationAppBundle.php` and chek if the namespace is `Destination\AppBundle`

**third:** check if the classname declaration is the same as the filename (in your case : `DestinationAppBundle`)

Answer (score 4):

Update composer.json like this:

```
"psr-4": {
    "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
    "UserBundle\\": "src/UserBundle"
},
```

After edit composer.json YOU MUST RUN `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

Verify in AppKernel.php the use of this class DestinationAppBundle

And the namespace in the class DestinationAppBundle

Answer (score 0):

What is the namespace in your DestinationAppBundle.php ?

It should be :

```
<?php
namespace Destination\AppBundle;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the namespace and service definition are right you can try:

- Upgrade Symfony version. I had an strange issue with Symfony 2.8.11, new services added gave me a ClassNotFoundException. Upgrading to 2.8.17 solved it.
- Try remove app/cache/* contents
- Check if you are using a pre-generated boostrap cached file without the "--no-dev" option (composer dump-autoload --optimize --no-dev --classmap-authoritative) and launch command again.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses PSR autoload.

You need to configure autoload in the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
```

This will include all files and folders under the \src folder